# mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 403: OK

Tags: python, authentication, mechanize, http-status-code-403, login-script

What I attempted multiple times:
1. changing headers to cheat it, doesn't work
2. tried on form `nr=0`, `nr=1`, and `nr=2` also doesn't work
3. confirmed username and password is correct
4. the same script worked for other similar website.

All attempts will return error:

> mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 403: OK

Other existing questions on stackoverflow would have cases of `403: Forbidden` and `403:Forbidden by robots.txt`, but don't really have this unique case with "OK".

```
# !/usr/bin/python

import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_debug_http(True)
br.set_debug_redirects(True)
br.set_debug_responses(True)

br.set_handle_equiv(False)
br.set_handle_gzip(False)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(False)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11'), ('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'),('Accept-Charset', 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3'),('Accept-Encoding', 'none'),('Accept-Language', 'en-US,en;q=0.8'),('Connection', 'keep-alive')]

def login():

    br._factory.is_html = True
    br.open('https://circleup.com/login/')
    #br.form.set_all_readonly(False)
    br.select_form(nr=2)
    br['username'] = '***********'
    br['password'] = '***********'
    br.method = "post"
    br.submit()


login()
```

result:

```
    br.submit()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 541, in submit
    return self.open(self.click(*args, **kwds))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 203, in open
    return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 255, in _mech_open
    raise response
mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 403: OK
```

Answer (score 0):

You got an **HTTP Error 403**, means an authentication error.
Although it is not a **407 Proxy Authentication error**, it could imply a proxy authentication problem with **mechanize**.

Do you work behind a **proxy**? If so, you should consider setting ~/.bash_profile or ~/.profile as;

```
export {http_proxy,https_proxy,ftp_proxy}=http://<username>:<pass>@<proxy_address>:<port>
```

If you've already set proxy, you could also get this error if you're running your script via **crontab**. If so, you should set proxy settings in crontab as;

```
http_proxy=http://<username>:<pass>@<proxy_address>:<port>
https_proxy=https://<username>:<pass>@<proxy_address>:<port>
```

I hope this works.